# What to do about clogged downspouts?

Tags: downspout

A picture is better than words...

[image: Water shooting up from downspout]

That's water shooting up from the connecting point during a heavy shower earlier due to the pressure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would cut the PVC and install a cleanout.  Once reassembled, you will always have access to the tile system.
[image]

Comment: Nice!  There's a pine tree nearby that sheds lots of needles annually, so that may be exactly what's needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Disconnect the down spout.**
This may require you to remove screws and/or rivets. Screws are easy, just use the appropriate driver and back the screw out. Rivets, however, will have to be drilled out. Select a drill bit just larger than the hole in the head of the rivet, place the tip of the bit in the hole and drill. You're not looking to drill straight through, you'll drill just enough so the head of the rivet comes off.

**Inspect the drain**
Now that you have access to the drain itself; using a flash light, inspect the opening looking for blockages.

**Clear the drain**
You might get lucky here and be able to clear the drain by hand, or blow the clog out using a garden hose. If not, you'll want to snake the drain out using either a handheld or drill powered drain auger.

[image]

**Reassemble**
Once the drain is running freely, reattach the downspout using your preferred fastening method.

***Warning:***
**DO NOT** use chemical drain cleaners. Some areas tie gutters into the storm sewer system, which may drain directly into nearby rivers and streams.

Answer (score 4):

Short term: Buy an elbow, cut the downspout and run a 15 foot gutter away from the house.

Long term:  Get a drain specialist in to snake it out and fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get access to a wet/dry shop vac, you may be able to suck the gunk out.